# Does the second parameter `options` exists for `readdir` function in `fs` module?

Tags: node.js, fs

When I pass "utf8" as the second parameter to the `readdir` function in the `fs` module (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback), it gives the following error:

```
fs.js:78
throw new TypeError('callback must be a function');
^
```

See the following snippets:

**Snippet #1**

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.readdir(process.argv[2], "utf8", function(){
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

---

**Snippet #2**

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.readdir(process.argv[2], function(){
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

---

Snippet #1 throws error, while Snippet #2 works.

Why does this happen? Doesn't `readdir` function have the second optional parameter?

Comment: What node.js version? (run `node -v` on the command line)

Comment: Both variants work fine with Node 7.0.0, while the first one reports the error with Node 4.6.1.

Comment: `fs.readdir('/tmp', 'utf8', (err, data) => {console.log(data)});` working on node `6.7.0`, you seem to be using an older version

Comment: Exactly! I'm using an older version v5.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be running an older version of node.js.

`v5` and previous did not support passing `options`. https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v5.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback

This was added in `v6.0.0`.

- CHANGELOG: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V6.md#notable-changes-14
- Revelant PR: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/5616

Comment: Exactly! I'm using an older version v5.x. My bad :)

Comment: Not at all your fault: the documentation doesn’t mention that options was added in 6.0.0, which is a *catastrophic* failure of the documentation.